# Append legends. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to add legends the plot when it adds a curve. I can't see whats wrong with my code, can someone please help? I'm using matlab r2015a on ubuntu.

```
x=1:5;
v=1:5;
plot(x,v)
[~,~,plots,str] = legend('1');

hold on
for i=4:10
pl=plot(x,v*i);
[~,~,plots,str]=legend([plots;pl],str,num2str(i))
end
```

when i run it i get:

```
plots = 

  1x2 Line array:

    Line    Line


str = 

    '1'    '4'

Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being
concatenated are not
consistent.
```

So its means it works the first lap but not the second.

Comment: what's wrong with it? I get 8 curves with the legend being `1 4 5...10`.

Comment: sorry, forgot to write the problem. There.

Comment: still, I don't see what's wrong. You code works fine when I try it. Did you copy it exactly as it is?

Comment: yes, exactly as it is

Comment: ah ok that explains the problem. I'll write an answer (now I'm at work with R2015a and indeed there is an error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the way Matlab handles `legends` is different than in earlier releases; they are now legend objects.

In any case, to solve your problem, which is a dimension mismatch problem, you can simply concatenate vertically the outputs you get using the `transpose` operator, because Matlab returns a horizontal array of line and text objects whereas you want a vertical array. Therefore, using `plots.'` and `pl.'` works fine. Also, it's good practice not to use `i` as a loop counter since it represents the imaginary unit.

```
clear
clc
close all

x=1:5;
v=1:5;
plot(x,v)
[~,~,plots,str] = legend('1');

hold on
for k=4:10
pl=plot(x,v*k);
[LegendObject,~,plots,str]=legend([plots.';pl.'],str,num2str(k));
end

%// Use the legend object to modify its properties/location
set(LegendObject,'Location','NorthWest');
```

Output:

[image]